# Annotations with arguments @field:Size(max = 100) not working on data class - KOTLIN

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, bean-validation

I have a data model class in Kotlin where javax validations with arguments are not working.

My model class:

```
data class Data(
    @field:Size(max = 100, message = "Message must be less than 100 characters")
     val message: String? = null
)
```

However, if I put something like @field:JsonIgnore without any parameters. The constraints do get implemented.

My service class has @Validated/ @Valid annotations

Comment: Remove `field` from annotation.

Comment: @IbrahimAlTamimi That's kotlin's way of doing binding can't do that ...

Comment: Which version of Kotlin you are using?